# Accessing array element in Ember handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple array in the controller:

```
App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
});
```

I would like to render the first element in the template; following instructions in other posts I'm doing:

```
{{items.[0]}}
```

Or this…

```
{{controller.items.[0]}}
```

…but the result is always nothing; am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. These should work ([demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/soveroku/2/edit)).
The problem lies somewhere else. Can't tell without more code.